# Enable/Disable internet not working for SONY Xperia (Any other way?)

Tags: android, android-internet

I am developing one Android app for that I need to **enable/disable mobile internet problematically**.

The code I have written for do this works fine with all other companies devices except **SONY Xperia Z**.

Is there any other way to stop the mobile internet in SONY?

**My code to enable/disable mobile data**:

```
       final Class conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
        final Field iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
        iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
        final Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField.get(conman);
        final Class iConnectivityManagerClass = Class.forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
        final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = iConnectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
        setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);
        setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, enabled);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To manage internet on Android device I use this code maybe it could help you:

```
ConnectivityManager dataManager  = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = dataManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();    
Method dataMtd = ConnectivityManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", boolean.class);

dataMtd.setAccessible(true);
dataMtd.invoke(dataManager, true); // set the correct boolean value to enable or disable internet
```

I have created a sample application to manage wifi and internet with Android if you need [more details](http://github.com/Alex-DG/internetAndWifi_management_android/blob/master/ConnectionManagement/src/com/project/connectionmanagement/MainActivity.java)